# UI Component Form Validation: Pattern method

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, uicomponent, adminform, form-validation

I've got an admin ui_component form which has a listing of fields and I'm adding validation to them.  One I'd like to use a custom pattern. The form in general works, it's just this "pattern" validation that's causing an issue.

So here is the relevant `<field>` setup from my `module_controller_form.xml` file:

```
    <field name="my_custom_filed">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">My Custom Filed</item>
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                <item name="source" xsi:type="string">model_name</item>
                <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">my_custom_field</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">1</item>
                <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="no-whitespace" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="validate-pattern" xsi:type="string">/^[a-z][a-z0-9_.-]$/i</item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </field>
```

The above *generally* works.  I get a javascript error about the string `/^[a-z][a-z0-9_.-]$/i` not having the method `test()`.  According to `validation.js` I see the content for the `pattern` validation method as being:

```
    "pattern": [
        function (value, element, param) {
            return this.optional(element) || param.test(value);
        },
        'Invalid format.'
    ],
```

When this code runs, it runs with the following invocation:

```
validations['pattern']('Test String', [element], "/^[a-z][a-z0-9_.-]$/i")
```

Sadly, it is passing the value of the `<item>` node as a string, instead of translating that to a `RegExp` object.

Is there a way to specify the validation pattern from the `*_form.xml` and have it properly transform the value to a regular expression object?  I haven't really seen any core modules use this validation within their XML declarations, but it seems like it should still work.

**UPDATE**

I'm still looking into this, trying to find where the form XML for the `validation` node is translated into the javascript bindings.  Does anyone know where I can start searching for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a core bug within Magento itself.  The string for the regular expression isn't being converted properly using `new RegExp()` or if you provide a native regular expression (e.g. `/[a-z][a-z0-9]+/i`) it's not interpreted as such.

I submitted the issue via GitHub and confirmed that it exists in Magento CE 2.1.7 as well as the EE.  Hopefully they fix the bug in the next release.

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/9919

**EDIT:** As of Magento 2.2.2 this has been fixed.

Comment: Were you able to get this working Brett? I found that if I take the slashes off the ends, the page will at least load without an error. However right when that validation starts trying to be checked it throws the same error anyway. Looking at the javascript it looks like the expression is coming in as a string and it should be working properly.

Comment: No, nothing yet.  I came upon this issue then got side-tracked by another project (or really two) so haven't had a chance to look at this too in depth.  It is on Magento's radar, just not sure how close it is to being fixed.